# Java Spring form check whether a input string contains special characters or not

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a Java Spring form that checks whether the input string contains special characters or not. For example when a user types in a string containing special characters a message will pop up stating that the input string contains special characters.

My question is how to implement java function to check for special characters in the input string?

Model

```js
 package com.mkyong.customer.model;

public class Customer {
 
 String userName;

 public String getUserName() {
  return userName;
 }

 public void setUserName(String userName) {
  this.userName = userName;
 }
 
}
```

Controller

```js
package com.mkyong.customer.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer;

public class TextBoxController extends SimpleFormController{
 
 public TextBoxController(){
  setCommandClass(Customer.class);
  setCommandName("customerForm");
 }
 
 @Override
 protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
   throws Exception {

  Customer customer = (Customer)command;
  return new ModelAndView("CustomerSuccess","customer",customer);
 
 }
 
}
```

CustomerForm

```js
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {
 color: #ff0000;
}

.errorblock{
 color: #000;
 background-color: #ffEEEE;
 border: 3px solid #ff0000;
 padding:8px;
 margin:16px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Java Textbox Special Characters</h2>

<form:form method="POST" commandName="customerForm">

<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Keyword:</td>
<td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
<td><form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

CustomerSuccess

```js
<html>
<body>
<h2>Java Textbox Special Characters</h2>

Keyword: ${customer.userName}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: My question is how to implement java function to check for special characters in the input string?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a list of all special characters and check it with regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=\\\\?@#|/'<>.^*()%!-]"); // fill in any chars that you consider special

if (regex.matcher(stringToCheck).find()) {
    // found
}
```

You can also look into [`Guava's CharMatcher`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) (no regex and more readable). You can construct your own matching logic like so:

```
boolean isAMatch = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE
    .or(CharMatcher.anyOf("[$&+,:;=\\\\?@#|/'<>.^*()%!-]")) // fill in any chars that you consider special
    .matchesAnyOf(stringToCheck);
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be matchesAnyOf? Otherwise it will check if all special characters are in stringToCheck

Answer (score 0):

Separate method for convert special character

```
if(checkSpecialChar("^[^<>{}\"/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*\\]\\\\()\\[¿§«»ω⊙¤°℃℉€¥£¢¡®©0-9_+]*$", source){
    // add your staff here
}

public boolean checkSpecialChar(String regex, String source) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
    return matcher.find();
```

Answer (score -1):

In Spring you can get the value of your Form like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userName")String username){
    // And now you can check with the regex pattern from hovanessyan if it contains special characters
   Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=\\\\?@#|/'<>.^*()%!-]");
   if (regex.matcher(username).find()) {
      // found
   }
}
```

I hope it helps.